# C# Sum of digits of a number if the sum equals 9

Tags: c#, numbers, sum, digits

i want all the numbers with 3 digits that have the sum of 9 to be write in the console.
This is what i came up so far and it doesnt work:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int n = 100; n < 1000; n++)
        {
            while (n <1000)
            {
                sum += n % 10;
                n /= 10;
                if (sum == 9)
                Console.WriteLine(sum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you are using `sum += n % 10;` This means that once `sum == 9` is true, it'll never be true again as sum just keeps going up. You probably want to reset it to 0 at the end of each iteration. This could be done either by setting its value directly instead of incrementing  - `sum = n % 10;` or instead after your conditional, having `sum = 0;`

Comment: It's an easy fix, I'm sure if you'll spend few minutes to debug your variables step by step, you will see the problem

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre is correct, but there's more; sum starts of as 0, but after the first while loop, sum = 10. Then you reduce your for's counter making it = 10. Next loop, sum = 11, and n becomes 1. Your while will never exit

Comment: tried it both ways still doesnt work

Comment: @bixarrio how does sum become 11? It's a modulo operation, meaning that it returns the remainder of the division

Comment: Looking at you code - you initialise n to 100 in the outer for loop, then in the inner while loop you keep dividing by 10 - so it will be stuck in an infinite loop as it will always be < 1000

Comment: this looks like a projecteuler.net question, questions like this are made to help you improve your debugging skills and you should try to go through your code. You could use the visual studio debugger to go through you code line by line, then you would be glad you solved it yourself and someone else did not do it for u.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre yeah, it's my bad. I was doing this in my head and dividing instead of mod. My actual concern was that the op was doing processing on n, but that's been resolved in a later answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use three loops, one for every digit:

```
for (int i1 = 1; i1 < 10; i1++)
for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 10; i2++)
for (int i3 = 0; i3 < 10; i3++)
{
    if (i1 + i2 + i3 == 9)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", i1, i2, i3);
}
```

Comment: The answers which rely on a modulo 10, followed by divide by 10 until 0, do have the advantage of being more easily extensible to longer numbers should the requirement change.

Comment: I Agree with @PaulF. This is specific to this problem only. The modulo solution can easily determine them for anything but just setting the range. Nice solution anyway

Comment: If looking at a solution so specific - then wouldn't a two loop solution be better - once you have i1 & i2, then i3 = 9- (i1+i2) - no need to test the other 9 values of the i3 for loop.

Comment: With i1 & i2 already known, then there is only 1 possible solution out of 10 - so you calculate it, if the answer is negative then there is no possible solution - so you only need an if statement you do not need to loop through 10 possible values.

Comment: Well, this is just a try to show OP a different approach for his specific problem. Since he seems to learn how to use loops i've shown a pure for-loop approach which reduces this mathematical problem to a very simple (and efficient) task. Of course there are other more flexible approaches that work too. If the task was to learn the modulo my approach prevents it in a funny way.

Answer (score 2):

You're not resetting sum after every loop iteration. sum should equal zero at the start of every iteration like. Also, the while loop is wrong. Try this:

```
for(int n=100;n<1000;n++)
        {
            sum=0;
            int i = n;
            while(i!=0) {
                sum += i % 10;
                i /= 10;
            }
            if (sum == 9)
            Console.WriteLine("Number {0} has digit sum of {1}", n, sum);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why soo commplicated?

```
for (int n = 100; n < 1000; n++)
{
    var s1 = n/100 % 10;
    var s2 = n/10 % 10;
    var s3 = n/1 % 10;

    var sum = s1+s2+s3;
    if (sum == 9)
    Console.WriteLine(n);       
}
```

For people, who dont like easy way :D

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(x => x.ToString())
    .Where(x => x.Length == 3).Select(x => new {x, sum=x.ToCharArray()
    .Select(c=>int.Parse(c.ToString())).Sum()}).Where(x=>x.sum == 9)
    .Select(x=>x.x).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Oki, tried to create non-generic but fastest solution.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if ((i>1 && j == 0) || i < j)           
        {                   
            Console.WriteLine(i * 90 + j * 9);              
        }
    }
```

Comment: The second one is also for people who like their programs to run x1000 times slower haha

Comment: The answers which rely on a modulo 10, followed by divide by 10 until 0, do have the advantage of being more easily extensible to longer numbers should the requirement change.

Comment: @PaulF disagree. Requirements can be changed in different ways, and inner loop can be advantage or disadvantage

Comment: @PaulF, that does not make any difference between the LinQ query and the traditional division technique. They both require almost the same changes. However, the main concern is SPEED. Here it is creating multiple enumerables which costs LOTS of time that can be easily saved otherwise. He did it just for fun anyway

Comment: @AmmarSalman think that PaulF answered on my first question ```Why soo commplicated?``` => its not about linq, its about using inner ```while``` loop (see others answers) instead just calc 3 numbers manually.

Comment: @tym32167 i get that but the real complexity isn't in the syntax. What matters is performance and those inner loops your using degrade performance for this specific problem when compared to the traditional solution

Comment: @AmmarSalman so, how do you think, which answer is the fastest here?

Comment: @tym32167 From your two solutions the first one is by far faster than the second one. It does not create any ranges and try surfing them. It is straight forward

Comment: @AmmarSalman that obvious. I meant, from all answers in whole question

Comment: @tym32167 For this particular problem, the chosen answer is the fastest. It only executes one command (check and do) per actual loop iteration. Your answer involves declaring 4 variables  and setting them each iteration and then make the check.

Comment: I wasn't commenting on the "Why so complicated" more on the "why so specific" issue. Unless there were serious time/space issues then I would design a solution for re-usability - an inner while loop would allow the outer for loop to be modified without constraint.

Comment: @AmmarSalman: there is a faster 2 loop solution if you see my comment to Tim's answer.

Comment: oki, I tried to make fastest solution, what do U think (updated answer)? @AmmarSalman

Comment: How about "for (var i1 = 1; i1 <= 10; i1++)   for (var i2 = 0; i2 < (10 - i1); i2++) Console.WriteLine($@"{i1}{i2}{9 - (i1 + i2)}");" for a solution without if statements

Comment: Ooops - first loop should be _"for (var i1 = 1; i1 < 10; i1++) "_ , though it still works because of the condition in the second loop.

Comment: @PaulF  nice alg  :D

Comment: Of course, if speed was absolutely critical & I had a spare 90bytes (45 shorts) of memory, I would pre-calculate the 45 values for this very specific case & store them in an array & loop the array. ;-)

Comment: Why use `Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)` and check for `Length == 3` rather than just start your range with `Enumerable.Range(100, 900)`?  You could at least eliminate that part.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway  that was a joke-sample to show how given problem can be solved in easy but not efficient way. So, that ```0-1000``` enumeration is not slowest part of code :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (int n = 100; n < 1000; n++)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                int num = n;
                while (num != 0)
                {
                    int r = num % 10;
                    sum += r;
                    num /= 10;
                }
                if (sum == 9)
                    Console.WriteLine(n);//.....Number whose all digit sum ==9
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: ty for helping but it doesnt exit the while

Comment: @toni what will be the output of n /= 10; ?

Comment: if you're changing n how is the for loop going to execute correctly?